# Como crear select por cada elemento en un array asociativo que recibo como respueta de un post ajax

Tags: javascript, php, html, json

Estoy trabajando en una web con CodeIgniter, necesito crear un select por cada elemento que recibo en un array o json. no sé cuál sea la mejor opción como respuesta de un post que realizo con ajax. El problema que tengo es que recibo un array como éste:

(Parte del var_dump)

```
array (size=5)
  'Monday 10' => 
    array (size=8)
      0 => string '16:00:00' (length=8)
      1 => string '16:30:00' (length=8)
      2 => string '17:00:00' (length=8)
      3 => string '17:30:00' (length=8)
      4 => string '18:00:00' (length=8)
      5 => string '18:30:00' (length=8)
      6 => string '19:00:00' (length=8)
      7 => string '19:30:00' (length=8)
  'Monday 17' => 
    array (size=8)
      0 => string '16:00:00' (length=8)
      1 => string '16:30:00' (length=8)
      2 => string '17:00:00' (length=8)
      3 => string '17:30:00' (length=8)
      4 => string '18:00:00' (length=8)
      5 => string '18:30:00' (length=8)
      6 => string '19:00:00' (length=8)
      7 => string '19:30:00' (length=8)
```

Y si recibo un json a traves de `json_encode` recibo algo como esto:

```
{
    "Monday 10": ["16:00:00", "16:30:00", "17:00:00", "17:30:00", "18:00:00", "18:30:00", "19:00:00", "19:30:00"],
    "Monday 17": ["16:00:00", "16:30:00", "17:00:00", "17:30:00", "18:00:00", "18:30:00", "19:00:00", "19:30:00"],
    "Monday 24": ["16:00:00", "16:30:00", "17:00:00", "17:30:00", "18:00:00", "18:30:00", "19:00:00", "19:30:00"],
    "Monday 31": ["16:00:00", "16:30:00", "17:00:00", "17:30:00", "18:00:00", "18:30:00", "19:00:00", "19:30:00"],
    "Monday 07": ["16:00:00", "16:30:00", "17:00:00", "17:30:00", "18:00:00", "18:30:00", "19:00:00", "19:30:00"]
}
```

No sé como acceder a cada elemento; ya he intentado iterar con la función `$.each` pero accedo a: `[,{,"` y asi sucesivamente. La idea es que me quede un label con el día, y en el select los horarios.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solo iteras el JSON con `for in` y el array de cada clave con `forEach` o `$.each` de jQuery.

```js
var data = {
    "Monday 10": ["16:00:00", "16:30:00", "17:00:00", "17:30:00", "18:00:00", "18:30:00", "19:00:00", "19:30:00"],
    "Monday 17": ["16:00:00", "16:30:00", "17:00:00", "17:30:00", "18:00:00", "18:30:00", "19:00:00", "19:30:00"],
    "Monday 24": ["16:00:00", "16:30:00", "17:00:00", "17:30:00", "18:00:00", "18:30:00", "19:00:00", "19:30:00"],
    "Monday 31": ["16:00:00", "16:30:00", "17:00:00", "17:30:00", "18:00:00", "18:30:00", "19:00:00", "19:30:00"],
    "Monday 07": ["16:00:00", "16:30:00", "17:00:00", "17:30:00", "18:00:00", "18:30:00", "19:00:00", "19:30:00"]
};

function createSelects() {
  for(let key in data) {
    var wrapper = createWrapper();
    var label = createElement('label');
    var select = createElement('select');
    
    label.textContent = key;
    data[key].forEach(function(hour) {
      var option = createElement('option');
      option.setAttribute('value', hour);
      option.textContent = hour;
      select.appendChild(option);
    });
    wrapper.appendChild(label);
    wrapper.appendChild(select);
    document.body.appendChild(wrapper);
  }
}

function createWrapper() {
  var section = createElement('section');
  section.classList.add('input-group');
  return section;
}

function createElement(tagName) {
  return document.createElement(tagName);
}
```

```css
.input-group {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px 40px;
}
.input-group > * {
  display: block;
}
.input-group label {
  font-family: 'segoe ui';
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 500;
}
.input-group select {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin-top: 10px;
  outline: none;
  padding: .4rem .65rem;
}
.input-group select:focus {
  border: 1px solid #777;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body onload="createSelects()">

  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias!!!